# Proving a vector space - help with identifying the symbol

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

V is a finite dim vector space and $T: V \to V$ is an operator. I need to prove $V \cong \operatorname{ker} T \times \operatorname{Im} T$.

I wasn't sure on what $\cong$ meant and how to get started with the problem. Any help or guidance on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: $\cong$  means "is isomorphic to".

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with kernels or images.  It can be rephrased as "What does this symbol mean?".  Given that you didn't know the meaning of the symbol at the time when you posted, you can't possibly have even attempted to answer the bit about kernels and images.  If you haven't yet even attempted a question, it's too soon to ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

1. $\cong$ usually means "is isomorphic to". "Isomorphism" is a word which has a meaning depending on the context. For example, in this case, you presumably wish to show that $V$ and $\ker T \times \operatorname{Im} T$ are *isomorphic as vector spaces.*
2. Two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are said to be isomorphic if there exists a linear function $T: V \to W$ such that $T$ is a bijection. (You may see a different definition but it would be equivalent to this.)
3. If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, one can show that $V \cong W$ iff $\dim V = \dim W$.
4. I presume you know the definition of the cross-product of vector spaces. One can show that $\dim(V \times W) = \dim V + \dim W$.
5. Thus, your question now simplifies to showing the following:
   $$\dim V = \dim \ker T + \dim \operatorname{Im} T.$$
   The above is simply stating the so-called "Rank-nullity Theorem".